# How to test Azure AD in Azure government?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-gov

I want to test some Azure AD features on Azure US government, but I don't know how. For normal azure active directory, I would go to demo.microsoft.com and create a tenant.

There, the only government related option is "World Wide Government" but there is nothing suggesting that it is actually on Azure Government cloud.
[image]

Also, after creating the tenant it says that it is in North America with "World Wide Government" content pack, which to me it means that it is on normal Azure.

[image]

So basically, the question is where to create a demo account and how to log in to the portal (is it still portal.azure.com)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go here and setup a free trial for Azure Government: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/global-infrastructure/government/request/